# fixed virtualenvwrapper now setuptools fails on pip install

Tags: django, heroku, pip, setuptools, distribute

I just got thru fixing virtualenvwrapper using this page as a guide:

http://www.jongales.com/blog/2012/07/25/fixing-virtualenv-after-installing-mountain-lion/#comment-37964

now when I got to `pip install -r requirements.txt` to get my Django project working Im failing on setuptools stuff?

anyone have some advices?

```
MacBook-Pro:staging macbook$ ls
Procfile        manage.py       settings.py     urls.py         wsgi.py
local_settings.py   medint          settings.pyc        urls.pyc
local_settings.pyc  requirements.txt    stuff           wiki
macBook-Pro:macbook$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-1.4.1.tar.gz (7.7MB): 7.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

Downloading/unpacking distribute==0.6.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading distribute-0.6.10.tar.gz (389kB): 389kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package distribute

Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url==0.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading dj-database-url-0.2.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dj-database-url

Downloading/unpacking gunicorn==0.14.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading gunicorn-0.14.6.tar.gz (219kB): 219kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gunicorn

Downloading/unpacking mailsnake==1.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading mailsnake-1.6.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mailsnake

    file mailsnake.py (for module mailsnake) not found
Downloading/unpacking newrelic==1.5.0.103 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading newrelic-1.5.0.103.tar.gz (186kB): 186kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package newrelic

Downloading/unpacking psycopg2==2.4.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz (719kB): 719kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
Downloading/unpacking requests==0.14.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading requests-0.14.2.tar.gz (361kB): 361kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

    warning: no files found matching 'tests/*.'
Downloading/unpacking simplejson==2.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Downloading simplejson-2.6.2.tar.gz (53kB): 53kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package simplejson

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wsgiref==0.1.2 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
Installing collected packages: Django, distribute, dj-database-url, gunicorn, mailsnake, newrelic, psycopg2, requests, simplejson
  Running setup.py install for Django
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 644 to 755

    changing mode of /Users/tmacbook/Envs/medint2/bin/django-admin.py to 755
  Running setup.py install for distribute
    Before install bootstrap.
    Scanning installed packages
    Setuptools installation detected at /Users/tmacbook/Envs/medint2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
    Egg installation
    Patching...
    Renaming /Users/macbook/Envs/medint2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg into /Users/macbook/Envs/medint2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg.OLD.1356316395.42
    Patched done.
    Relaunching...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'install' is not defined
    Complete output from command /Users/macbook/Envs/medint2/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/macbook/Envs/medint2/build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/qm/dvrz87yj6px11mw0sxcy88lh0000gn/T/pip-RJZBEP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/tmacbook/Envs/medint2/bin/../include/site/python2.7:
    Before install bootstrap.

Scanning installed packages

Setuptools installation detected at /Users/macbook/Envs/medint2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg

Egg installation

Patching...

Renaming /Users/macbook/Envs/medint2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg into /Users/macbook/Envs/medint2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg.OLD.1356316395.42

Patched done.

Relaunching...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'install' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/macbook/Envs/medint2/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/tmacbook/Envs/medint2/build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/qm/dvrz87yj6px11mw0sxcy88lh0000gn/T/pip-RJZBEP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/tmacbook/Envs/medint2/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/tmacbook/Envs/medint2/build/distribute
Storing complete log in /Users/tmacbook/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 2):

upgraded distribute==0.6.32

that seems to fix it.

Comment: Is this a bug in distribute 0.7.3?